# Ordenar un QuerySet

Tags: python-3.x, django

alguien me puede ayudar a ordenar un queryset  tengo esto:

```
resultados = transaccional.objects.filter(ordenpaciente_id=pac.id).order_by('examen_id').distinct('examen_id')
```

Quiero reordenarlo por otro campo de otro modelo, he intentado esto pero no me funciona:

```
resultados_final = resultados.objects.order_by('examen.grupoExamenes_id')
```

Esto también he intentado:

```
resultados = transaccional.objects.filter(ordenpaciente_id=pac.id).order_by('examen.grupoExamenes_id','examen_id',).distinct('examen_id')
```

Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Falta la definición de los modelos para saber como esta la relación entre los 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder de un modelo a otros debe utilizar dos guiones bajos (`__`). A continuación un ejemplo:

#### Modelos

```py
from django.db import models

class Resultado(models.Model):
    examen = models.ForeignKey(
        Examen,
        related_name='resultados',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )


class GrupoExamen(models.Model):
    pass


class Examen(models.Model):
    grupo_examen = models.ForeignKey(
        GrupoExamen,
        related_name='examenes',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

#### Consulta

```py
Resultado.objects.order_by('examen__grupo_examen_id', 'examen_id')
```

#### Documentación

- [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)